# Customer Experience: Enable Acquiring Company to See Subsidiary's Cases but Not Vice-Versa

Tags: sharing-sets

We have a Self Service Experience site  for a customer support use case. All the licenses are of type `Customer Community`

We use Sharing Sets to ensure that these users can only see their own company's cases

```
Object      Access Determined By                      Access Level
Case        User:Contact.Account = Case:Account       Read/Write
```

Now, we have a situation wherein users of `MegaCorp` want to be able to see their own cases as well as the cases of `AcquiredCorp`. But `AcquiredCorp`'s users should only be able to see `AcquiredCorp`'s cases, never the cases of `MegaCorp`

*Example*

```
  Case                           Who can see/edit
  Case.Account = MegaCorp        MegaCorp users
  Case.Account = AcquiredCorp    MegaCorp and AcquiredCorp users
```

How do we do this without resorting to Customer Community Plus licenses which open up Sharing Rules and Account Relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution (there could be others) is as follows:

**Account hierarchy**

Create this account hierarchy

```
      MegaCorp  (no contacts, no community users)
        |
        | -- MegaCorp Support (all MegaCorp community users associated to contacts of this account)
        |
        | -- Acquired Support (all AcquiredCorp community users associated to contacts of this account)
```

**Create a new Profile**

- Name it something like `ParentWithVizToSubsidiaries Community Login`
- Ensure that all the community users of `MegaCorp Support` use this Profile

**Create a new Sharing Set**

```
Object      Access Determined By                      Access Level
Account     User:Account.Parent = Account:Parent      Read only (optional)
Case        User:Account.Parent = Case:Account.Parent Read/Write
```

- The second sharing set rule is the important one.
- Assign this sharing set to the new Profile `ParentWithVizToSubsidiaries Community Login`

**How it works**

*Remember that the users of `MegaCorp Support` are using the new profile/sharing set*

- All of the `AcquiredCorp` cases will have an `Account.Parent` of `MegaCorp`
- All of `MegaCorp Support`'s cases will have an `Account.Parent` = `MegaCorp`
- All of the `MegaCorp Support` users will also have an `Account.Parent` of `MegaCorp`
- Thus they can see both sets of cases, their own as well as `AcquiredCorp`'s

Users of `AcquiredCorp` are using the sharing set defined in the OP:

```
Object      Access Determined By                      Access Level
Case        User:Contact.Account = Case:Account       Read/Write
```

- That sharing set only lets them see their own cases, never cases from other accounts (so the MegaCorp cases are invisible)

Comment: I've been reliably informed that `Account Contact Relations` is another option - though it creates difficulties with Contact merging